# Any suggestions for constantly updating data in postgres on the heroku platform?

Tags: ruby, database, postgresql, heroku, sinatra

Using a Sinatra Ruby web server, I'm having trouble figuring out how I can get certain fields in my postgres server to update every X amount of time.

Anyone have any suggestions for a way to change data every X number of minutes while still handling normal http requests.

Comment: Do you really need to update this data in the database, or can you use unchanging data in the DB to create a time based derivative that solves your problem? You are courting performance problems if you plan to do enormous database updates at scale.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the Heroku Scheduler addon? It allows you to schedule a rake task every 10 minutes.

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/scheduler